# How to remove a field from POJO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

```
public class user {

    private String planId;

    private String eid;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Collection<String> userIds;

}
```

I have a pojo like above

and the code which is use for creating the json request object is this :

```
    public UserCollection getUserCollection(final user args) {
            Map<String, String> headersMap = new HashMap<>();
            ObjectMapper jacksonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            jacksonMapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS); // this line is creating the userIds field to reflect
 //By any code we can remove the userId field from the args object
    
            String responseBody = null;
            String responseStatus = null;
                String jsonRequestBody = jacksonMapper.writeValueAsString(args);
    }
```

I just want to remove userIds from the args by not removing any of the above code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [`@JsonIgnore`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html)? This is useful if you want to ignore this field in both serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Yes i have tried. but the code  "jacksonMapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);" is ignoring all anotations, i need some code which can different from annotation and remove the field userId

Comment: `jacksonMapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS)` limits all possibilities about annotations, is it mandatory ? If yes one alternative is create a new class without the field and serialize it.

Comment: Yes it s mandatory. Can’t make another class need to make some changes here only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you should solve this without removing the annotation processing code, you should maybe add a custom serializer. You can read further about the topic at [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization).

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        User myItem = new User("planId", "eId", List.of("1", "2"));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(User.class, new UserSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(myItem);
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class User {

        private String planId;
        private String eId;
        private Collection<String> userIds;
    }

    public static class UserSerializer extends StdSerializer<User> {

        public UserSerializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public UserSerializer(Class<User> t) {
            super(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(User value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException{

            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField("planId", value.planId);
            gen.writeStringField("eId", value.eId);
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

If you had to use it without annotations, and cannot add a custom serializer you should map the User class into a more specific class without the field in question and then serialize that one.

Comment: Not possible. The pojo can’t be modified.

Comment: You do not have to change the POJO if you use the custom serializer. Can you change it? Even the serializer can be an inner class so you don't have to create another file.